# How to input more data into an input in the terminal (python)?

Tags: python

hi so i am a fairly new to coding as i am still in highschool and i am just doing coding to kill sometime waiting for the next semester to start. Can someone please help me with this problem? Here is my code:

```
    students=[]
    def students_get_title():
        students_titlecase=[]
        for student in students:
            students_titlecase= student["name" ].title()
        return students_titlecase

    def print_students_title():
        print(students_get_title())

    def add_students_name(name, studentid):
        student = {"name": name, "studentid": studentid}
        students.append(student)



    student_name= input ("Enter your name : ")
    student_id= input("Enter your id :")
    add_students_name(student_name, student_id)
    print_students_title()
    response = input("Do you want to add more?")

    if response== "yes":
        student_name = input("Enter your name : ")
        student_id = input("Enter your id :")
        add_students_name(student_name,student_id)
        print_students_title()
and here is the response:
Enter your name : Dwika
Enter your id :45
Dwika
Do you want to add more?yes
Enter your name : Cloud
Enter your id :65
Cloud
```

Now what i want to have is, the name cloud appearing after Dwika for example : Dwika, Cloud,etc;. I want to be able to put so many names automatically and my code would keep on adding the names into it automatically how do you do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get superior answers.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Python, Dwika!

You may use a `while` loop to add in as many names as you want and use the last question as a condition for breaking out of the loop.
Here's an example:

```
while True:
    student_name= input ("Enter your name : ")
    student_id= input("Enter your id :")
    add_students_name(student_name, student_id)
    print_students_title()
    response = input("Do you want to add more?")
    if response != "yes":
        break
```

Let me know if you have any other queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code in a `while True` loop.

```
while True:
    student_name= input ("Enter your name : ")
    student_id= input("Enter your id :")
    add_students_name(student_name, student_id)
    print_students_title()
    response = input("Do you want to add more?")

    if response.lower() != "yes": 
    #Any input that is not 'yes' or 'Yes' will break out of the loop
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to So! I advise you to read about [loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp). Whenever you want to repeat a task a given number of times, or in your case indefinitely, you need to you need to use a looping construct to keep repeating a block of code

For example, a part of your code might look like this

```
response == 'Yes'
while response == 'Yes':
  # this block of code keeps on repeating till the value of response remains Yes
  student_name= input ("Enter your name : ")
  student_id= input("Enter your id :")
  add_students_name(student_name, student_id)
  print_students_title()
  response = input("Do you want to add more?")
```

You should spend some time familiarizing yourself with the fundamentals of Python and programming languages in general and Python's syntax([this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp) might be useful) and then writing such scripts will become a cakewalk for you

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Python. Awesome that you are taking steps in function programming. Just to help you, you don’t have to repeat yourself again(asking users to enter username and if) and also title function is an overkill. If I were you I would restructure my code as this:

```
students = {'name': [],'id': []}

def print_students(students):
    # print students names
    if students['name']:
        print(', '.join(name for name in students['name']))



def add_students_name(students, name, studentid):
    # append names and ids
    students['id'].append(studentid)
    students['name'].append(name)


def get_students(students):
    # make student.title() happens here

    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    studentid = input('Enter your ID: ')

    # add then to our dictionary
    add_students_name(students,name.title(), studentid)

    # if we have names print them
    if students['name']:
        print_students(students)


    # ask if user want to add more  
    response = input('\nDo you want to add more? ')

    # accept users yes or y else exit
    if response.lower() in ('yes','y'):
        # call the function again(Loop)
        get_students(students)
    else:
        print('\nGood bye!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # call your function
    get_students(students=students)
```